# Table not showing inside MODAL

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My Markup is this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
         aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <form action="{{ url('/hr/') }}" method="post"  class="form-horizontal " enctype="multipart/form-data">
                           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}" />
                            <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                  <td >Document Type</td> 
                                  <td  >Document Number</td> 
                                  <td >IFSC is applicable</td>
                                  </tr>                              
                            </table>
                          </form>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And I am firing the modal is like this

```
$('.submitKyc').on('click',function(){

    $('#myModal').modal('show');

});
```

But the Table is not shown inside the modal instead it is printed on the browser body

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: It is showing perfectly at my end

Comment: Did you prepend it just before </body> tag??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w02auavu/1/

Comment: @ManishJangir no I am adding it in one of my views and After that I have footer etc I don't know whats the problem

Comment: May be there is a HTML markup issue. Please check your HTML

Comment: @ManishJangir yes I figured There was another table before this which was not closed , I closed that and now its working fine